# CSS to fix vertical logo alignment in Wordpress issue with Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, windows, google-chrome

The vertical alignment for the site logo for http://bigidearesults.com/ in Firefox on Windows 10 is correct and centered vertically, but Chrome on Windows 10 for some reason aligns the logo to the top.

The logo image is nested in a number of divs:

```html
 <div id="site-banner" class="cf nothing logo">
    <div id="site-banner-main" class="no-right">
      <div id="site-banner-left">
        <div id="site-banner-left-inner">
          <div class="site-branding">
              <h1 class="site-logo"><a href="http://bigidearesults.com/" rel="home"><img src="http://bigidearesults.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
```

Please let me know the CSS code to get this logo to center vertically in Chrome on Win 10, like it does in FireFox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by flexbox. You need just add on your `#site-banner-left-inner` selector the next code. It is friendly for most of all browsers.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: center;
```

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) about it. You can solve you problem for Chrome easily.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the `display:table` from `#masthead_TesseractTheme .site-branding` (line 416) and `.site-branding` (line 402), so the `display:table-cell` form the ***other*** (?) `#masthead_TesseractTheme .site-branding` (line 67) is applied fixes the issue.

You got a lot of conflicting rules there.